# How do you say 'I'm glad to hear that' ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I'm asking about situations where you expect to hear a bad news but you get a good one, like at a doctor's visit.

Answer (score 6):

For once, the literal translation works:

- "Ravi de l'entendre" ou
- "Je suis ravi d'entendre ça"

Or, as suggested by @Damien, since the news could have been bad but turned out to be good:

- "Je suis soulagé de l'entendre"
- "Je suis soulagé d'entendre ça"
- "Quel soulagement!"

(soulagement = relief)

Comment: Can we say 'content d'entendre' too?

Comment: Yes you can, it's a bit less intense than "ravi" but it works very well too. If you want to emphasize the idea of relief, you could also use "soulagé" (relieved). In the context that you described, that is the verb I would use naturally: "Je suis soulagé de voir que ce n'est rien de grave".

Comment: @Karlom, no, that's what you would say after a temporary hearing loss. "content d'entendre ça" would work though.

Comment: "Ravi de l'entendre" is not  idiomatic (anglicism); the typical form is "Ravi de vous l'entendre dire.".

Comment: @Karlom "Ravi d'entendre" is not idiomatic, not at all.

Comment: @LPH so please add the idiomatic ways of saying it as an answer.

Comment: @Karlom There are several ways but in general you have to have a complement (ça, le, …): "Ravi de vous l'entendre dire.", "Ravi de vous entendre dire ça.", "Ravi d'entendre ça de votre part."; note that in the last case "dire" is not used. Other possibilities:"Ravi de vous entendre dire ces choses.", "Ravi de vous entendre dire cela."

Comment: @LPH's What makes you believe *ravi de l'entendre* is not idiomatic ?? or an anglicism ??

Comment: @jlliagre It seems I never heard it said like that, and moreover, whereas in English you say "I heard that they were coming to town.", in French you say invariably "J'ai entendu dire qu'ils vont venir dans notre ville.".

Comment: @Karlom Take what LPH writes with a grain of salt. He often asserts with confidence things that are completely false.

Comment: @LPH What relationship do you make between *ravi de l'entendre* and the remaining two sentences? In any case, your second statement is false, *J'ai entendu qu'ils venaient en ville* is a closer and better translation.

Comment: @jlliagre https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=J%27ai+entendu+dire+que%2Cj%27ai+entendu+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CJ%27ai%20entendu%20dire%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20entendu%20que%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CJ'ai%20entendu%20dire%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj'ai%20entendu%20que%3B%2Cc0 De nombreux faux positifs pour « j'ai entendu que ».

Comment: @LPH  Il y en a peu, peut être 10% dans les texte récents. De toute façon, quel est le rapport avec la choucroute ?

Comment: @jlliagre C'est ce que je pensais, une  introduction récente, inconsidérée, à partir de l'anglais.

Comment: *Sire Thibaut de Champagne, **j'ai entendu que** vous avez convenancé & promis à prendre à femme la fille du Comte Pierre de Bretagne...*, Abbé de Choisy, *La vie de Saint Louis*, 1690. Une introduction récente ?? à partir de l'anglais ??

Comment: Si l'on s'attendait à une mauvaise nouvelle, on peut aussi dire *je suis soulagé de l'entendre*

Comment: @Damien, merci, réponse mise à jour